# Binaural recording: monitoring with 'bone conduction'? 

Tags: binaural, monitoring, recording, headphones

Hi,
I was thinking about buying a bone conduction headset for monitoring binaural recordings.
It would be used to hear if there's any wind noise or low battery beeps from my recorder.

Does anyone have any experience with bone conduction headphones? How does it sound? 
Can one expect a normal headphone sound or is it different?

Thanks in advance!

Arnoud

Answer (score 1):

I have a pair of these Binaural microphones from Roland which have monitors built in to the earphone. The only time I've ever dealt with feedback issues is if the monitoring level is very high.  I've use them quite a bit for field recording and recording impulse reponses and really enjoy them.  The price is right too. Email me if you'd like to hear some test recordings. phil dot lichti at gmail dot com.

http://www.roland.com/products/en/CS-10EM/

Comment: That's a crazy cool idea. Are there any issues with rustling noises with your own body movements or the cables?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no advice, but after a quick google I found that this 'bone conduction' idea is used for hearing aid implants. However, the hearing aid is screwed into the skull so a much more structure-bourne transmission occurs. http://bit.ly/YTGXGG

I wonder how effective a snug fitted headset is.. perhaps a 'try before you buy' may be in order. But a very useful product if it is effective. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your response. I can't find a place that sells the headsets in the physical shop... the downside to internet shopping.